# Is it possible to couple an inbuilt MySQL database with my C++ program?

Tags: c++, mysql, database, wxwidgets, desktop-application

This may be a rookie question as I'm new to building desktop software(I only have web dev experience). Suppose I build a C++ GUI app(with something like and wxwidgets) that connects to a MySQL server on my desktop. This could be a library management system. How can I build it so that when I distribute it to other people, they wouldn't need to install MySQL on their system, they just have to install my program and be good to go(similar to using something like SQLite). Is something like this possible? I know this can be done with a database on a cloud service but I want to have it on each user's own PC. Can we do something like that instead of having to install a MySQL server on each user's system?

Comment: Why not use SQLite as you've already mentioned in your question? What you're describing; SQLite is your best bet

Comment: Mysql being open source (if allowed by the licence) you could in theory build the server components into your application but it'd be a lot of work, just use sqlite which is designed for this purpose

Comment: Maybe not so much work required: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/libmysqld.html

Comment: @nethrenial, it all depends on what you want to do with mySQL and what OS you are using/targeting.